# Django - link one model fields to another model's fields

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using the below definition for two `models` of my app:

```
class AreaMap(models.Model):
    Code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fCityCode = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='City', max_length=100)
    fCountyCode = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='County', max_length=100)
    fCountryCode = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Country', max_length=100, default='RO')
    CityPicture = models.ImageField(upload_to='cities')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fCityCode

class Book(models.Model):
    Code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    fUser = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Belongs to')
    MainDescription = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Description/title', max_length=100)
    fCityCode = models.OneToOneField(
        AreaMap, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='City')
    fCountyCode = models.OneToOneField(
        AreaMap, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='fcountycode')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.MainDescription
```

According to my model definition (which is wrong), both fields from my second model inherits the same values that comes from `fCityCode` belonging to the first model. What I want is that in my second model, for fields `fCityCode` and `fCountyCode` to be able to select only the values that are being held in the first model, in the same columns - `fCityCode` and `fCountyCode`.

How can I achieve something like this? Thanks

Comment: Do you not just want a foreign key from `Model2` to `Model1` instead of those fields? `Model1` should probably have the foreign/one-to-one keys to the `AreaMap` model?

Comment: @IainShelvington - I modified my question. Actually my `model1` is `AreaMap`.The point is that I want to be able to select to which city and county my `Book` object belongs to.

Comment: Seems like it would make sense if both of those fields were replaced by 1 foreign key from `Book` to `AreaMap`

Comment: @IainShelvington - imagine that to more cities belongs to the same county. This is what I am trying to achieve. If I would do as you suggest, I will be able to select only one value in my `Book` model - either city or code, correct?

Comment: The `Book.fCityCode` field being one-to-one implies that each `Book` belongs to 1 city? In your models `AreaMap` and a "city" seem synonymous?

Comment: @IainShelvington - correct. Each `Book.fCityCode` belongs only to one city.

Comment: If you renamed `AreaMap` to `City` and added a foreign key from `Book` to `City` would that make more sense?